# python dataframe groupby and append new columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Below is my code so far:

```py
business_card_list = [[20180401, 'IT', 'anna'],
                      [20180401, 'IT', 'ena'],
                      [20180401, 'IT', 'sunna'],
                      [20180401, 'ART', 'jejus'],
                      [20180401, 'ART', 'zico'],
                      [20180401, 'ART', 'joker']]

business_df = pd.DataFrame(data = business_card_list, columns=['date', 'job_name', 'user_name'])
print(business_df)
```

[image]

I want to change `business_df` to such pictures below form through grouping.
Do you offer in Dataframe?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help!

```
business_df.groupby(['date','job_name'])['user_name'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `groupby` with `apply`, `rename` and `add_prefix`:

```
print(business_df.groupby(['date', 'job_name'])['user_name'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns=lambda x: x+1).add_prefix('user_name_').reset_index())
```

Output:

```
       date job_name user_name_1 user_name_2 user_name_3
0  20180401      ART       jejus        zico       joker
1  20180401       IT        anna         ena       sunna
```

Comment: @조원영 GIRISH kuniyal's answer is missing the part of renaming the functions...

Comment: @U10-Forward Your rename  function made my day, one upvote from my side ;) !!